# Disable weak ciphers in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, encryption, weak

Our scan reports show weak cipher enabled for Jenkins. Jenkins is running on windows 2012. The java path is default path in Jenkins.xml .I tried to update the java.security file. It still shows the weak cipher. Not sure if I'm missing anything. Any recommendation on how to fix it? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What Jenkins ver, JDK ver? Did you read [Disabling Specific Ciphers In Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216526298-Disabling-Specific-Ciphers-In-Jenkins) ? note:-[JIRA-39895](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-39805) is resolved despite the article words.

Comment: Thank You. Yes, tried this . But no luck.